# Angular open new tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to make that at each new tab instead of being displayed in a new page if displayed as in the images below?

I advanced on my problem is it possible that at each click a new mat-tab is formed and becomes clickable?

Thanks in advance.

**Each image corresponds to a new tab I hope to have been clear**

[image: capture]

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="align-link">
      <div>
        <p>Lien 1</p>
      </div>
      <div (click)="link()">
        <p>Lien 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="One">
        <div class="example-small-box mat-elevation-z4">
          Small content
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts.file**

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  goToAcceuil() {
    this.router.navigate(['/accueil']);
  }

  link() {
    window.open('https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview', '_blank');
  }
```

Comment: Hello, the question is not really clear, but through what I see, do you mean that you want to open each content in the mat-tab instead of opening it in a new Browser Tab/Window ?

Comment: You are welcome, through what the documentation says : you may look at [this simple example](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.ts) through [this documentation page](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)